# Can't access internal testing on google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I've uploaded my app to internal testing and my testers that were able to see the beta version of the app before can't see the app now. Even the opt-in url is not working.

[The error below says that the app is not available for the account but I am logged in with the gmail address used in for testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOcdy.png)

Comment: did you accept the internal testing requests?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey Nidhin. Is the internal testing request the button on the play store to Join the beta program? or is it something else